# setting character encoding for hyperjaxb3

Tags: maven, plugins, hyperjaxb

Is there a way to set the character encoding of files generated by the maven hyperjaxb3-plugin? 
Out of the box, the Java files generated are encoded with ISO-8859-1 character set (at least on my Windows machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work automatically in the next version (0.5.7, yet to be released).

Support for encoding was implemented in one of the last versions of XJC (2.2.5) and consequently in maven-jaxb2-plugin version 0.8.1. This functionality should be inheried by maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin in the next version.

Encoding can be configured in plugin configuration (`encoding` element). By default it is `${project.build.sourceEncoding}`.

If you're not using Maven, just use the `-encoding` option of XJC.